#  Is it possible to have the javascript properly execute smooth scrolling with the anchors in nav.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modularity

I am trying to create a modular html document that employs smooth scrolling.

If I don't place the anchors directly in the document it does not scroll smoothly.

http://www.cincitucky.com/ is the site.

http://www.cincitucky.com/_scripts/script.js shows the loaded html elements with "nav.html" deprecated because I had to place it directly in index.html for it to work properly.

Is it possible to have the javascript properly execute smooth scrolling with the anchors in nav.html?

I checked in thoroughly before asking up here. I wish,someone could help me in this regard.

Also, is there a great site that explains how to ameliorate/solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you load the nav element via (asynchronous) ajax call, your links are not available at document ready event, so in your external `script.js` change this

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
...
```

into this

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
...
```

doing so you will capture the event on `body` element through its propagation (this technique is called *event delegation*)

Comment: Thank you! It works great, I'm going to read up on event delegation.